# Both setEnabledSystemUIOverlays and setPrefferedOrientation in flutter

Tags: flutter

I've made an app that plays a video and I have some custom controls on top of the video on a stack. What I want to do is when the video page opens, set both `setEnabledSystemUIOverlays` and `setPrefferedOrientation`. This works when opening the video page but does not return to its normal state when I go back to the home page. I want to restore `setEnabledSystemUIOverlays` and `setPrefferedOrientation`  when I'm back at the home page. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: add the code you're using

Comment: What's the difference between setEnabledSystemUIOverlays and setEnabledSystemUIOverlays?